# PtrToStringUni doesnt work in windows 10

Tags: c#, marshalling

So i have been using `urlmon.dll`'s help with getting the MIME type of files' data as suggested in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature/1685614) answer, and its been working fine in windows 7.

However, on windows 10 the same code generates `System.AccessViolationException` when trying to create a string from the mime pointer.

this is the problematic code:

```
uint mimeType;
FindMimeFromData(0, null, data, 256, null, 0, out mimeType, 0);
var mimePointer = new IntPtr(mimeType);
//Exception is thrown on the next line
var mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimePointer);
```

The code works fine on windows 7 and on the same files, however when running this on windows 10 i suddenly get Access Violation.

Did anyone else encounter this error ?

Comment: have you ran it in administration mode?, also is there a reason you cant get the `mimetype` from the files extension?

Comment: @AndrewE yes i have tried running as administrator and it doesnt work (wouldnt be a solution either because normal users are going to use it on company computers, with no admin privileges). and i do take extension into consideration, but many times the file types i work with dont match the extension (blame our customers) and i prefer to check it myself.

Comment: Windows 10 was released 3 years ago so this isn't a "did anyone else encounter this" error. It's the only supported Windows version now. The buffer may be too small, or the pointer is the wrong type, or you may have used the 32-bit version of the DLL on a 64-bit machine. At the very least, post the full exception including its call stack. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`.

Comment: @Banana just to try, have you tried changing the `Platform Target` to x64

Comment: @AndrewE yes i have, in fact it was the first thing i tried but to no avail

Comment: just to try, (not a solution) what happens if you run the exe in Windows 7 compatibility mode?

Comment: @AndrewE tried this too, same problem.

Comment: When you say you can't get the mimetype from its extension, where you accessing the registry to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uint mimeType;
FindMimeFromData(0, null, data, 256, null, 0, out mimeType, 0);
var mimePointer = new IntPtr(mimeType);
```

This is surely wrong at 64 bits... A `IntPtr` is 64 bits (it is a memory address)... How could a `uint` (a 32 bits) contain it?

And if we take a look at the [pinvoke site](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.findmimefromdata) the signature should be:

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
static extern int FindMimeFromData(IntPtr pBC,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzUrl,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.I1, SizeParamIndex=3)] 
    byte[] pBuffer,
    int cbSize,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzMimeProposed,
    int dwMimeFlags,
    out IntPtr ppwzMimeOut,
    int dwReserved);
```

**very important** while the documentation of the method is very poor on msdn, calling `FindMimeFromData` will cause a memory leak: you have to free the `ppwzMimeOut` you receive... The problem is that it isn't clear how: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20647203/613130) it is suggested to use `CoTaskMemFree`, that is `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`. I'll say that it is right, tested with:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("someimage.jpg");

while (true)
{
    IntPtr ptr1;
    int success1 = FindMimeFromData(IntPtr.Zero, null, bytes, bytes.Length, null, 0, out ptr1, 0);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr1);
}
```

If I remove the `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem` and take a look with the TaskManager, the memory used by the process will go up quite quickly... If I restore the `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`, the memory will remain stable.

Comment: your point makes sense, but it worked just fine on windows 7 64bit, whats different in windows 10?

Comment: @Banana Not all 64 bits addresses need 64 bits... Some stay under 4gb and so are castable to 32 bit. But clearly it is random

Comment: the computer im testing this on has 4gb of ram so there are no qualifying addresses to cause this problem

Comment: @Banana There is a difference between physical memory address and virtual memory address. Your 4gb of memory can be mapped to any address.

Comment: @Banana If I have to make an educated guess, I'll say that the changes Microsoft made to `ASLR` (Address Space Layout Randomization) between Windows 7 and Windows 10 caused memory allocations to go over the 4gb "border" of virtual space. One of the possible randomizations is about the bottom-up memory allocation (see  [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2013/12/11/software-defense-mitigating-common-exploitation-techniques/)), and I'll say that *that* is what caused the memory address to go from "very low" (< 4gb) to "random" (> 4gb)

Comment: i just tested the code with the declaration you suggested and using `IntPtr` instead of `Uint` and it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Banana Note what I've added at the end of the response: you must free the memory received my `FindMimeFromData`

Comment: yes i haven't included it in the question's code but i am freeing the memory. had to figure it out the hard way...